# How to get UILabel to resize better?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

I am trying to make my multiline `UILabel` as small as possible with given max-width, but the `sizeToFit()` and `sizeThatFits(_,_)` methods aren't giving the results I want.

Take a look at this image:
[image]
The red rectangle represents the width that I pass in `sizeThatFits` (while height being Max). Obviously, as you can see, this method does in fact return *a size that fits*, but it does not give me the smallest size possible, which I want.

Let's say I specified `max-width: 300`. This actual result is giving me a size of ca. `280*50`.
As you can see in the image, the text is now written like this:

```
Here is some text that is supposed to
align nicely
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
Here is some text that is
supposed to align nicely
```

This result would've had the same height, but a much smaller width, e.g `200*50`
I realize that it's difficult to define "smallest size possible", as it could return this:

```
Here
is
some
text
that
...
```

Or even just a single letter per line. But given that `sizeThatFits` returns this, with a given width and height, why doesn't it return my wanted result, which is the same height, but with **smaller width**. Why isn't the smallest fit returned? Does a function like this exist?

Comment: did you tried label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.7 or 0.8 ?

Comment: I think you need to set textAlignment to center

Comment: @RahulVyas `MinimumScaleFactor` has nothing to do with this. and no, I don't want the text to align center. Even if I use `textAlignment=.Center`, it breaks the sentence at the same place, making the text `align nicely` standing alone on the next line.

Comment: I don't think you can find it in original implementation, you might have to implement it yourself by restricting number of characters in a line after calculating the number of lines to be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own solution, which works pretty well:

```
private func calculateWantedSize(label:UILabel)->CGSize{
    var lastAcceptableWidth = label.bounds.width
    let currentHeight = label.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: label.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.max)).height

    var tempHeight = currentHeight
    while(tempHeight == currentHeight){
        let newWidth = lastAcceptableWidth - 1
        tempHeight = label.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: CGFloat.max)).height
        if tempHeight == currentHeight{
            lastAcceptableWidth = newWidth
        }
    }
    return CGSize(width: lastAcceptableWidth, height: label.bounds.height)
}
```

Here I'm sending my label to a function which first calculates the current width and height of the label, then loops through width-1 and checks the resulting height until the height is changed. The height will change when the width is so low that it needs a new line. When this happens, I return the **last valid width** which still needed the same height as original.

This is perfect for my problem, using attributed text etc.

Of course, when using this, be sure to do some checking before calling. I don't know what will happen if you use this function when the label has a single word, or a single letter, or no text at all. I have only tested this for the cases I know will happen with this app, and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Sti,

You can try this buddy :) I have been using it and seems to do a pretty good job :)

```
CGRect rect = [yourText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth_you_Can_afford, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                             options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]}
                                                             context:nil];
```

The rect after executing will have the minimum width and height that will be required to render the text :)

Once you have the frame now you can set the same for your label and set the text as well :)

I have used it in chat bubble :) and it works well :)

Happy coding :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me.. gives me a slightly different, yet still the same result. A few fractions of a pixel different.. Strange. Are you sure there's nothing else you are doing?

Comment: Hmmmm nothing else buddy :| I am using it with a lable having width constraint on it and depending on the rect value I update my chat bubble width and it works absolutely fine. Have you set the label's  font size to be 16 and style to System font ?? This method highly depends on UIFont if you provide font different in label and different in calculation text will not be properly wrapped

Comment: @sti : And out of curiosity asking why do you need min space ?? Usually UILabels makes use of intensic size and it wont acquire un-necessary extra space. I did it because I can let my chat bubble to start from one side and end at other there nust be a gap so I specified max width as 70% of screen width may I know what exactly are you trying to do ???

Comment: I need it to be as small as possible, given a maximal width of e.g `300px`. Meaning that `200px*50px` is better than `280px*50px`, because it is smaller. It is what the designer has designed, so it is what I will develop. If the label uses more than one line, I want it to distribute the words so that it uses the least amount of space as width as possible. Why have a single word on the next line *alone* when we can make the width smaller and have the same width on both lines? That is what I'm trying to achieve. As illustrated in the question.

Comment: And yes, I did set the font to the same font as the label. This is all made programmatically (not Storyboard or anything).

Comment: Never use "buddy" more than once per conversation.  ;-)  That would be too familiar.  You can use "dude" as many times as you want.  Unless you're talking with your son -- then use "buddy" all you want, but don't annoy him with it...too much.  :-D